# Jquery MixItUp2, filtering values between 2 values

Tags: jquery, mixitup

I'm trying to setup a webshop using mixitup (https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) for filtering/sorting of products.

This is the site as it is atm. (in danish though):
http://www.boerkopcykler.dk/katalog2/74/0/Cykelcomputere_GPS

Everything is working as intended, BUT i have been asked to make a slider, to specify
a price range to show.

I have searched on google on every imaginable (for me) searchstring to find out if it's possible or not.

Neither have i been able to discover anything in the docs, and im not a js novice.

I'm hoping someone has any ideas about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to filter your elements by their `data-price` attribute and then call `mixItUp`, passing the `'filter'` parameter first, then the filtered elements:

```
// Here are your limits, as set by your slider or whatever..
var min = 2400, max = 3000,
    $container = $('#frmvareliste');

// Filter the mixed elements
var $show = $container.find('.mix').filter(function(){
    var price = Number($(this).attr('data-price'));
    return price >= min && price <= max
});

// Call mix it up to.. well.. mix it up..
$container.mixItUp('filter', $show);
```

Comment: That actually works perfect, tyvm! :)

Then i just need to figure out how to combine it with the other filters, any ideas?

Comment: @MartinDK Glad to have helped (:

Comment: It was a BIG help :) Just can't seem to figure out to combine it with the other filters

Comment: I would have thought you could just use jQuery's `add()` to merge the elements in `$show` together. Ask another question if need be, remember to have a go at it yourself first though (:

Comment: I will go take a swing at it myself first :)

Comment: Good luck. Maybe see you soon.